# Distribution - App Store Provisioned App runs on Test Devices

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution, provisioning, adhoc

Is there anyone who can answer this?  It really doesn't make sense and I want to avoid getting rejected later.....

I have created a **single Distribution Certificate** for my company.

I have successfully used this for Adhoc distribution, linking it to an **Adhoc Provisioning Profile** which includes all the test devices.

I have also submitted the App to Apple with a separate **App Store Provisioning Profile** (has App Store selected and does not have any devices linked to it) but the same Distribution Certificate.  It was rejected but that was due to a bug that only appeared in the Release Build config and I've sorted that now.

As part of resolving that, I found that I could copy the Release config built App (which uses the App Store Provisioning Profile) to my devices and it runs fine.

Whilst that was handy for resolving the issue, I didn't think I would be able to run it on my devices.

Am I missing something or does Apple allow this now?

Am I right to use the same Distribution Certificate on both? - **YES - thanks @Swapna**

I'm wondering if in fact the App I submitted was somehow built using the Adhoc Provisioning Profile and that it will fail when it finally gets released.

I've also heard that I should create a new Provisioning Profile for each submission.  Is that right and if so, why? - **NO - thanks @Swapna**

Many thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same distribution certificate for Ad Hoc profile and App store distribution profile.

However separate provisioning profile has to created and downloaded for Ad hoc distribution and App store distribution.

If you need to upgrade an existing app, you will have to use the same Provisioning Profile you had created while submitting your application to iTunes for approval. New Provisioning Profile should be created, only if the application is a new one.

Comment: Thanks @Swapna, but I'm still baffled that I can use the App Store provisioning profile which is not linked to devices to test on a test device.  If that's the case, why would anyone bother to use the Adhoc distribution with its limit of 100 devices and the need to get UDIDs.  Surely I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found this too. We submitted a build to the App Store and I have also dragged it into iTunes, synced it to my phone, and found it working. I can't find any other information on this.

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that for once, I created a single distribution certificate where I chose Ad Hoc instead of App store, built and tested the app on a few devices. Then, instead of using my other distribution certificate (where I chose App store rather than Ad Hoc), I just submitted the same binary to the appstore, expecting an error message. Interestingly, the App store accepted the binary. Now, I hope there will not be a problem of rejection, or, even worse, the app goes live but can only run on the test devices I specified when I chose the Ad Hoc distribution option.

Sitting back and waiting ..

Comment: @funkybro what do you mean?

Comment: So you said, "sitting back and waiting" (to see if your app was accepted, and if it was, if it ran on all devices); this was in November 2012.  Was wondering if you had had a result since then?

Comment: ah yes, it was accepted without a problem. no stream of angry complaints from people who downloaded it and couldn't run it because we didn't specify their UDID. which corroborates what Swapna wrote